# Java prompt user to enter a day

Tags: java, prompt

How do I get this syntax to prompt the user to enter a day? I know it has to do with line 5. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
public static void main(String[] args) 
{

    System.out.print("Set day: ");
    Day d = new Day(Sunday);
    d.print();
}
```

Comment: Look up Scanner and System.in

Answer (score 1):

Use a `Scanner`. This will allow you to prompt the user to input and the console will wait for the user to do so. Cheers.

```
import java.util.*;

public static void main(String[] args) 
{

    System.out.print("Set day: ");
    Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
    String in = scan.nextLine();
    Day d = new Day(in);
    d.print();
}
```

Comment: Don't say thanks :P Show it with upvotes in the future.